# Did not get into the desired grad school, what should I do?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

So I'm about to graduate from a university in the U.K., and my grad school application did not go perfectly. I got an offer from a top 10 (globally and in the U.S. domestically) math program, however, I don't really like the city the university is in, and in fact the uni itself. I have visited the school when I was doing undergrad applications, and I just didn't like it from the beginning. Thus I am frustrated about what I should do:

option 1 is I go there and apply for another Ph.D. program after two years. This Uni definitely has some reputations in the field, and I think it will be helpful for my application in the future. However, I have also heard some negative comments regarding students attending the school (not on the department specifically, but on the school as a whole).

option 2 is I can do master at my current school, which is G5 in the U.K. and also ranked around 10-ish globally in math, and apply for a Ph.D. program later.

The problem with option 2 is that I want to eventually go back to the U.S. for Ph.D. if possible, and this year's failure makes me question how admission officers in the U.S.value U.K. certificates. I have a quite solid 1-st class score(or 3.9+/4.0 GPA), GRE math 90%, GRE 324, 3 research experiences (two of them were required for all students, but U.K. undergrad has only two summers...), and have given talks on the non-required summer project. Recommendation letters writers also have had experiences working as professors in schools like Harvard. I realize that my resume is nowhere near strong, but among almost 20 schools I applied to, only one school give me a master's offer (I applied to all Ph.D. programs since most schools don't separate the master program). Thus I am not sure how a one-year master can change the result for my Ph.D. application later. I can probably increase my standardized test scores by a bit, but I don't think that's the main reason I failed this year.

Also there's option 3, which is to transfer after the first year of my master's program, but I heard it's very difficult and not encouraged.

I would really appreciate some advice and insights regarding my situation right now, and some info about how U.S. admission officers value U.K. schools are very helpful as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "G5 in the UK" mean? And why did you apply to somewhere you already knew you didn't like?

Comment: Anyway, I think your question might be closed as it's too specific to your situation, but I think the best thing for you to do is try and get some research experience before applying again. A UK BSc (as you allude to) does not really give a student the opportunity to do real research. Perhaps doing a Master's first will help you.

Comment: Life as an undergrad is very different than life as a graduate student. And what bothered you 4 years ago may not be very important today.

Comment: @astronat Sorry, that's my first time using this forum and I don't know how to phrase my question better. G5 is 5 universities in the U.K., namely Cambridge, Oxford, Imperial College London,  University College London, and London School of Economics. I applied because of the school's reputation in the field. Three years ago I didn't like the school because of its campus and environment, but I figured that for grad school, academic is more important than the environment.

Comment: @astronat I am hesitating again now because I just talked to a few of my friends studying there (different department), and they gave me some rather negative comments on the general atmosphere among the students there. Despite all that I agree I really lack research experiences, and I do hope to do more research during my master's program. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for the advice, and I agree with you. I didn't like the school mostly because of its campus and the city it is in. However, academics is, after all, the most important in order to pursue a career in academia. I think I will accept the offer, and hopefully find out that it's not as bad as I've imagined!